# Dcast Function -> Reorder Columns

Tags: r, dplyr, rows, dcast

I used the dcast function to show the spendings per month of different companies. Of course I want January first, then February etc. and not the alphabetical order.

```
Spendings <- data %>%
    filter(Familie == "Riegel" & Jahr == "2017") %>%
    group_by(Firma, Produktmarke, `Name Kurz`) %>%
    summarise(Spendingsges = sum(EUR, na.rm = TRUE))

Spendings <- dcast(data = Spendings, Firma + Produktmarke ~ `Name Kurz`, value.var="Spendingsges")
Spendings

                Firma               Produktmarke     Apr     Aug     Dez     Feb     Jan     Jul     Jun     Mai     Mrz     Nov     Okt     Sep
                Company1           Product1          228582 1902138  725781      NA  709970      NA  265313  228177      NA      NA 1463258 4031267
```

Is there a way to reorder the colums **dynamically** ? For 2018 for example the dataframe is shorter, so i can not use:

```
Spendings <- Spendings[,c("Firma", "Produktmarke", "Jan", "Feb", "Mrz", "Apr", "Mai", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Okt", "Nov", "Dez")]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    Spendings_raw <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = 14, nrow = 0))
colnames(Spendings_raw) <- c("Firma", "Produktmarke", "Jan", "Feb", "Mrz", "Apr", "Mai", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Okt", "Nov", "Dez")
Spendings_raw

Spendings <- data %>%
    filter(Familie == "Riegel" & Jahr == "2017") %>%
    group_by(Firma, Produktmarke, `Name Kurz`) %>%
    summarise(Spendingsges = sum(EUR, na.rm = TRUE))


Spendings <- dcast(data = Spendings, Firma + Produktmarke ~ `Name Kurz`, value.var="Spendingsges")
Spendings <- rbind.fill(Spendings_raw, Spendings)
```

This works perfectly ;-).